# Java methood split() not working with comma, array out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, split

I am trying to separate a string of an address entered by a user that is divided by commas. For example, If the user input the address

`"4367, 56th Avenue, Vancouver, BC, V4K1C3"`

I want and array with the values

`array ["4376", "56th Avenue", "Vancouver", "BC", "V4K1C3"]`

With indices 0 through 4. However, when implementing this in one of my classes, I keep getting an Array out of bounds errors when I assign the value of `array[1]` to a variable - As if everything is going into the 0 index of the array. Here is a snippet I wrote up that illustrates the issue:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  String fullAddress = input.next();

  String[] arr = fullAddress.split(",");

  System.out.println(arr[0]);
  System.out.println(arr[1]); //error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
  System.out.println(arr[2]);
  System.out.println(arr[3]);
  System.out.println(arr[4]);


 }
}
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: What does your debugger tell you fullAdress contains?

Comment: ^ This. A debugger would have solved this problem in a matter of seconds ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is you are using `next()` which uses `<space>` as delimiter. With given input as:

`4367, 56th Avenue, Vancouver, BC, V4K1C3`

Using `next()`, you end up `fullAddress = "4367,"`. On split you get `arr = ["4367"]`, hence you get exception at `arr[1]`.

Use `nextLine()` instead.

```
String fullAddress = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`. You also should use the following regex to avoid the spaces:

```
String[] arr = fullAddress.split(",\\s+");
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with `next()`

```
String fullAddress = input.next();
```

as it just reads just the input, not the end of line or anything after the input.
You need to change it to

```
String fullAddress = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

**use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`**

> `next()` will only return what comes before a space.
>
> `nextLine()` automatically moves the scanner down after returning the
>   current line.

for your input `4367, 56th Avenue, Vancouver, BC, V4K1C3`

your `fullAddress` contains `4367,` so after `split()` you have only 1 item and your are trying to access 2nd element so you are getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
 String fullAddress = input.nextLine();

 String[] arr = fullAddress.split(",");

 for(String k : arr)
 System.out.println(k); //better approach to avoid out of bound exception
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use split with comma, don't forget to use `trim()` on each token because if you have something like this: `"4367, 56th Avenue, Vancouver, BC, V4K1C3"`  the array will look like this:

```
array ["4376", " 56th Avenue", " Vancouver", " BC", " V4K1C3"]
```

There will be leading space without `trim()`

Comment: It is better to directly split with a proper regex to avoid the need for trim() afterwards. See my answer.